# How to put string to CssClass with Eval in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, eval

When I run the code below in a  in the aspx page, its working without any problem.

```
<%# (DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ExtendedProperties['ShowDetail']")) == null ? "show showdetail" : ( (bool)(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ExtendedProperties['ShowDetail']")) == true ?  "showdetail hide" : "show showdetail ") %>
```

But when I put it on an attribute of a button, it says the server tag is invalid. What is the problem

```
<asp:Button ID="btnShowDetail" OnClick="BindRecommendation" Text="" runat="server"
CssClass='<%# (DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ExtendedProperties['ShowDetail']")) == null ? "show showdetail" : ( (bool)(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ExtendedProperties['ShowDetail']")) == true ?  "showdetail hide" : "show showdetail ") %>' BorderStyle="None" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Your string mixes `"` and `'` - the inner `'` end up delimiting the ends of the `CssClass` attribute value.

You need to use *one* type only.

A complication is that to evaluate an indexed property using a string, you must use C# strings, so `'` is not a valid delimiter and you *must* use `"`.

You can escape `"` in the HTML source by doubling them:

```
ExtendedProperties[""ShowDetail""]
```

Comment: @Ryu - Actually your comment does say _what_ is not working and what error/warning/exception you are getting. Can't help with that kind of comment.